# Read iPhone Settings Programmatically (Precisely Settings->General->Date & Time->Set Automatically)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

We are developing an iPhone application for which i need to read iPhone Settings value (precisely the status of 'Settings->General->Date & Time->Set Automatically'). Is there any way easy/difficult way to find out that value? Any tips and tricks will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code (I just found this out by examining the contents of the `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/` directory on my iPad):

```
NSDictionary *pref = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.timed"];
BOOL autotime = [[pref objectForKey:@"TMAutomaticTimeEnabled"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"Automatic time is %@", autotime ? @"enabled" : @"disabled");
```

These keys are undocumented and you should probably not use them in an AppStore app. You can, however, safely use them in in-house apps or softwares for jailbroken devices.

Comment: for some reason the following code always gives me "disabled"
{
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  NSDictionary *pref = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.timed"];
  BOOL autotime = [[pref objectForKey:@"TMAutomaticTimeEnabled"] boolValue];
  NSString *sStatus = autotime ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"System Time" message:sStatus delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}
}

Comment: yeah, I ran it on my phone and it said the pref dictionary is nil.

Comment: @Senior what is your OS version?

Comment: @Senior Mine is 5.1.1, probably the keys changed.

Comment: probably a good reason not to try this in production then :^)

Comment: @Senior I **explicitly suggested not to use this in production.** "These keys are undocumented and you should probably not use them in an AppStore app" - Probably a good reason not to downvote...

Comment: this seems VERY flaky and evil -- technically ok (as expected), but this isnt good advice for .. in general

Comment: @Daij-Djan stop downvoting, OK? Should have read the FAQ... Downvotes should indicate either a technically incorrect answer or spam - this one is neither.

Comment: @H2CO3 "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter [...], or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." -- this is dangerous to me, I explicitly said it is technically sound even BUT said it isnt good advice in general

Comment: I'm with @Daij-Djan and Senior. This code may work but anyone looking for an answer for this question should not immediately see code that does not work in the App Store and does not have consistent behaviour across even the two latest versions of iOS.

Comment: i agree with H2CO3 and he clearly mentioned **"These keys are undocumented and you should probably not use them in an AppStore app. You can, however, safely use them in in-house apps or softwares for jailbroken devices".** It may be useful for someone who is writing an in house app for 5.0. There is no reason to down vote this answer.

Comment: Lal is possible to get Automatic date and time in iPhone

Comment: @ user529758  Hello, I need somewhat similar file access in iOS 10. How can I access the log files from Settings --> Privacy -->Analytics --> Data programmatically.Can you please help regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry, this is not possible.

Comment: I bet with myself there was going to be such an answer within less than 10 minutes.

Comment: You can congratulate yourself for winning the bet by upvoting my answer.

Comment: I'm not going to do that, since as far as I'm concerned, there is a way for getting this info :)

Comment: Yeah, but you can't use it in the app store!

Comment: @Senior I'd agree with you, hacking the OS isnt a real answer... / using another apps private structure here

Comment: @Daij-Djan how is "another app's private structure" used here?

Comment: you access another apps config file. I count that as another apps structure

Comment: @Daij-Djan Which app's config file am I accessing? (Hint: neither... this is a global configuration file.y)

Comment: a bit pedantic now ;) timed is an application, a process, a component of the os.. yes i should not have called it app